# Why BasicTextField (in compose) doesn't work well?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to use `BasicTextField` with `TextAlignment.End` for RTL. it's my code:

```kotlin
val textState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
val shape = RoundedCornerShape(CornerSize(4.dp))
BasicTextField(
    value = textState.value,
    onValueChange = { newText -> textState.value = newText },
    textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
        color = ColorPrimaryDarkText,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
        textAlign = TextAlign.End,
        fontSize = 14.sp,
    ),
    maxLines = 1,
    singleLine = true,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(32.dp, 0.dp)
        .clip(shape)
        .background(color = Color.White),
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
        imeAction = ImeAction.Done
    ),

    decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.White, shape)
                .padding(8.dp),
        ) {
            if (textState.value.text.isEmpty()) {
                Text(
                    text = "hint",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                )
            } else {
                innerTextField()
            }
        }
    }
)
```

it's OK when it's empty but it's not working well when you try to type anything (it's starting to type from center):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `textAlign = TextAlign.End` and use something like:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl ) {
    BasicTextField( /* your code */)
}
```

[image]
[image]

Otherwise if you want to use your code add `horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End` in `Row` in the `decorationBox` parameter:

```
    decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.White, shape)
                .padding(8.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End){
              //your code
     }
```

Comment: And can you please say why it's not working well with `TextAlign.End` ?

Comment: @HamidSj add `horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End` to the `Row` in `decorationBox` parameter.